# Use Enum in Entity Framework Database first?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-6

I have a prolem when use Enum for Database first.
I have two table:

```
Table1:
Id int
Label nvarchar(50)
StatusId int

Table2:
StatusId
Label
```

I created a Constrains key for two table, and in Asp Mvc. i load both into a Model.edmx. so I want to convert StatusId in Table1 to an enum for easy operation, but i cannot do it.

What is wrong? How can i do it? I don't want to remove Table2 from Model.

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`enum` is implemented in the `CLR` as an `int32`, but it is not an `int32`. It is a separate type, so you cannot use in the Entity Framework. But could use it to reference an `int32` in the other entity.

I would rather suggest to go Code First Approach for implementing your ideas.

Use this [link](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/simple-code-first-example.aspx) for details and samples about Code First Approach